# Remote control light socket

Tags: remote-control

Preferably, it would screw in to an existing light socket.  RC car type frequencies/range (27-49MHz or so).   No wifi, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would 310MHz be acceptable? If so, the well-developed [X10 system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_(industry_standard)) may be useful. An [introduction is available](https://www.x10.com/x10-basics.html). [Lamp socket](https://www.x10.com/x10-home-automation/modules/lm15a.html) modules [are available.](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dtools&field-keywords=x10%20lamp%20module%20screw-in&rh=n%3A228013%2Ck%3Ax10%20lamp%20module%20screw-in)

Comment: That is precisely what I was looking for.